# Image feature extraction with TF2 Keras API and TF Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

How should I use a tf Dataset in order run model.predict(data) and have access to the other features of the tf Dataset?

For example: my tf dataset has this format: 
(tensor<(100,224,224,3)>, tensor<(100,)>) -> preprocesses images as tf.float32, uuids of the images as tf.string

If I extract the feature vector like this:

```
for image_data, uuids in ds.batch(100):
    features = model.predict(data[0]) -> I get an array of features.

    At this moment features is an array of (100, 2048) and uuids is a tensor of (100,) tf.string
    How can I combine them in order to write the feature vectors to disk?
    From my understanding, I need to have both of them in the same format, either both tensors so I can continue using tf code and save the feature vector as a tfrecord, either to get the uuid as a string from the uuid tensor so I can use python code and save the array in the file using numpy.tofile.

    So my questions are:
    - How can I make the features to be a tensor?
    - Or can I get the string value from the tensor uuid?
    - Does anything sounds wrong in what I try to do? Is there a more optimal way to create the input pipeline? Or did I misunderstood the usage of Keras API and tf dataset?
```

If I use a python pipeline I can successfully save the array in a file. But I would like to use tf dataset because I think it's gonna be faster and more optimized due to it's parallel map function, batching and autotuning the parallel calls.